# Using CMD and WORKDIR instruction values from Dockerfile inside Helm template

Tags: dockerfile, kubernetes-helm

Please look at this simplified Helm template

```
{{- define "deployment" }}
{{- if .object.enabled }}
{{- $ := set . "projectname" "testproj"}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      {{- if .wd }}
      workingDir: {{ .wd }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .ep }}
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
      args:
        - |\
          for envvariable in $(find /tmp/envvariables -type f | sort -n); do set -o allexport; source $envvariable; set +o allexport; done && \
          {{ tpl (printf "%s" .ep) $ }}
      {{- end }}
      
{{- end }}
{{- end }}

{{- $_ := set . "object" (default dict .Values.service1) }}
{{- $_ := set . "sn" "service1" }}
{{- $_ := set . "ep"  "node src/index.js" }}
{{- $_ := set . "wd" (printf "/app/packages/%s" .sn) }}
{{- $_ := set . "in" ( printf "testproj-%s" ( .sn | replace "-" "_" ) ) }}
{{- template "testprojdeployment" .}}
---

{{- $_ := set . "object" (default dict .Values.service2) }}
{{- $_ := set . "sn" "service2" }}
{{- $_ := set . "in" ( printf "testproj-%s" ( .sn | replace "-" "_" ) ) }}
{{- template "testprojdeployment" .}}
---
```

Here, the template contains and set entry point (.ep) and working directory (.wd) for `service1`, but for `service2` they are not specified here in the template, and I want to take those value from the `service2` `Dockerfile` or just use its default `CMD` and `WORKDIR`, but I still need to pass environment variables to that container. I know that there is `envFrom` property and `configMapRef` or `secretRef` can be specified there (instead of exporting those variables inside `args` property), but my question is whether it is possible to do something like this:

```
      containers:
      {{- if .wd }}
      workingDir: {{ .wd }}
      {{ else }}
      workingDir: {{ .dockerfile.workdir }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .ep }}
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
      args:
        - |\
          for envvariable in $(find /tmp/envvariables -type f | sort -n); do set -o allexport; source $envvariable; set +o allexport; done && \
          {{ tpl (printf "%s" .ep) $ }}
      {{ else }}
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
      args:
        - |\
          for envvariable in $(find /tmp/envvariables -type f | sort -n); do set -o allexport; source $envvariable; set +o allexport; done && \
          {{ tpl (printf "%s" .dockerfile.cmd) $ }}
      {{- end }}
```

Notice those `.dockerfile.workdir` and `.dockerfile.cmd` properties, which I would like to be able to access.

Comment: I would almost always expect those details to be in the Dockerfile, so you don't need to repeat them in your Helm template.  The `args:` block looks sort of like an entrypoint wrapper script, again not something I'd try to write code as the output of more code.  You can specify individual `env:` variables or take `envFrom:` a ConfigMap, without any of the complexity you show here.  Is there a reason you're trying to construct a very complex command line at deploy time?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze! Thank you for your response! Actually, I'm not trying to build something complex. Vice versa, that is how it is built now and I just want to make a small change in order to be able to use `.wd` and `.ep` from the `Dockerfile`. Have I understood correctly that there is no option like `.dockerfile.cmd` or something similar?

Comment: If you specify Kubernetes `command:` (overriding the image `ENTRYPOINT`) then you must specify the actual command you want it to run; there's no way to retrieve the `CMD` from the Dockerfile.  This sort of resembles the Docker entrypoint-wrapper pattern and you could potentially move this script into your image, or use a Kubernetes-native path to set environment variables (how do the files get into `/tmp/envvariables`?).

Comment: @DavidMaze re `/tmp/envvariables` - that is a folder. It contains a set of files keeping env vars (`VAR=VAL` format). They are mounted as separate volumes.

Comment: Is the only thing you're doing trying to set environment variables?  Where do these volumes come from?  Instead of files, can you [use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data)?  (I keep asking this same essential question, because this seems like a very hard path to do something Kubernetes can do for you; even using Helm code to convert the flat key-value files to a ConfigMap is probably simpler.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, actually, environment variables + secrets (similar file structure, but files have a different format (`export VAR1 CLEAR_TEXT` and other variables on separate lines). I fully agree with you that `ConfigMap` and `Secret` would be a proper solution, but this task requires a bit more time for implementation. That is why I was trying to find a quick solution, even if it is not so good.